# Comparing two OntModels in Jena

Tags: java, comparison, rdf, jena, owl

I am trying to compare two different versions of an ontology by using java. OntModels are populated as "RDF/XML-ABBREV". But my results are not same as expected. I am checking if both models are isomorphic and the result is true. But when I iterate through the models it gives me results that they are different. Even if I load same version in both models still it gives me same results. I want to check if any class is deleted or added in the new version. How it is possible check for the changes?

```
        StmtIterator iter = model.listStatements();
        if (model.isIsomorphicWith(model2))
            System.out.println("Both are isomorphic");
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Statement stmt = iter.nextStatement();
            Resource toSearch = iter.nextStatement().getSubject();
            if (!model2.containsResource(toSearch)) 
                System.out.println("statement not found"+ toSearch);
        }
```

Comment: You're calling .nextStatement() twice in this example. This has the effect of skipping one statement for each statement examined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comparing RDF models, "isomorphic" means that the two models can be mapped 1:1 on to each other. This mapping uses equality for comparing any IRIs or literal values, but uses a correspondence mapping between blank nodes. The reason this is necessary is that *by definition*, a blank node is unique to the model in which it occurs, so simply comparing blank nodes for equality will always fail.

Two isomorphic models are, for all intents and purposes, identical. The reason your separate comparison (`model2.containsResource`) fails is that some resource in your model are blank nodes, so you are trying to compare blank node equality between models, which will fail.

> I want to check if any class is deleted or added in the new version. How it is possible check for the changes?

The `isIsomorphic` check will tell you if you need to look for any changes. If two models are *not* isomorphic, you should be able to find missing subjects in one model or the other *disregarding blank nodes*:

```
      Resource toSearch = iter.nextStatement().getSubject();
      if (!toSearch.isAnon() && !model2.containsResource(toSearch)) { 
              ...
      }
```

Note that this check isn't full-proof by the way, as you are merely checking for the addition/deletion of a subject. It might very well be that your change added a triple with an already-existing subject - and this check wouldn't find that change. But I'm assuming you *only* want to test for newly added/removed classes, in which case this should probably work. A more robust test might be that you loop over all `rdf:type` relations and check that the ones not involving blank nodes exist in both models.

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the statements between the 2 models.

Here is a Custom `RdfUtils` class with a `getStatementsDiff` static method :

```java
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RdfUtils {

    @NonNull
    public static StatementDiff getStatementsDiff(@NonNull final Model expectedModel, @NonNull final Model actualModel) {
        final StatementDiff diff = new StatementDiff();
        
        // Create list with expected statements
        final List<Statement> expectedStatements = new ArrayList<>();
        expectedModel.listStatements().forEachRemaining(expectedStatements::add);

        // Create list with actual statements
        final List<Statement> actualStatements = new ArrayList<>();
        actualModel.listStatements().forEachRemaining(actualStatements::add);

        // Find the missing statements
        expectedStatements
                .stream()
                .filter(expectedStatement -> actualStatements.stream().noneMatch(s -> s.equals(expectedStatement)))
                .forEach(expectedStatement -> diff.getMissingStatements().add(expectedStatement));

        // Find the excess statements
        actualStatements
                .stream()
                .filter(actualStatement -> expectedStatements.stream().noneMatch(s -> s.equals(actualStatement)))
                .forEach(actualStatement -> diff.getExcessStatements().add(actualStatement));

        return diff;
    }

    @Getter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class StatementDiff {
        private final List<Statement> missingStatements = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<Statement> excessStatements = new ArrayList<>();

        public boolean hasDiff() {
            return !missingStatements.isEmpty() || !excessStatements.isEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            if (this.hasDiff()) {
                return ">> missingStatements :: \n" + missingStatements.stream().map(Objects::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")) + "\n\n" +
                        ">> excessStatements :: \n" + excessStatements.stream().map(Objects::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            } else {
                return ">> No diff found";
            }
        }
    }

}
```